# Mimicking lookahead when it isn't supported

Tags: regex

I want to match all text that is encapsulated within `<?` and `?>`. I found a fairly easy way to do this using lookahead:

```
<\?([^?]|\?(?!>))*\?>
```

Unfortunately lookahead isn't supported by the tool I'm writing the regex for. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The selected answer is correct! On the other hand, there's no way to lookahead when not supported (with a regex pattern). Any kind of simulated lookahead will move ahead and two consecutive matches will fail. Real lookahead does not move the internal parser pointer, it just peeps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, you could simply make the repetition ungreedy:

```
<\?(.*?)\?>
```

This will only go until the first `?>`. Any single `?` before that will be covered by the `.*`, but when the engine encounters the first `?>` it will stop.

Note that (unless you use the `DOTALL` modifier) this will not work for sections going across multiple lines. If you cannot use the modifier, this will do (platform-independently):

```
<\?((.|[\r\n])*?)\?>
```

Comment: I changed that to `<\?((.|\n)*?)\?>` to make it work with multiline sections, but it appears to be working nicely. Thanks!

Comment: `.` does not match `\n` by default. That is what the `DOTALL` modifier is for (how to activate it depends on your tool).

Comment: Alright, I updated the newline to `[\r\n]`. Sadly the tool I'm trying to use the regex with (flex) doesn't appear to do anything with the regex. [This document](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Why-doesn_0027t-flex-have-non_002dgreedy-operators-like-perl-does_003f.html) appears to confirm this.